# How to kill all background and spawned processes of a bash script in its pre-exit handler?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, signals, wait, jobs

I'm using the `wait -n` technique to perform `max_jobs` parallel tasks:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cleanup() {
    echo "cleaning up..."
}

trap "cleanup" EXIT

do_task() {
    echo "doing task" "$1"  " ..."
    sleep 3s
}

main_task() {
    for ((j = 0; j < 10; j++)); do
        ((i++ < max_jobs)) || wait -n
        do_task "$j" &
    done
    wait
}

i=0
max_jobs=4

main_task
```

How can I kill all jobs and processes spawned by this script (in `cleanup` handler) if I hit `Ctrl+C` ?

I tried `kill 0` in `cleanup`, but it doesn't seem to kill the dangling `do_task` jobs.

Note that if I send `SIGTERM` (`Ctrl+C`) in first 3 seconds, it kills the script. But if I wait until 5s and then send `SIGTERM`, suddenly one dangling process consumes 100% of the CPU as if it is stuck in an infinite loop. I have to eyeball that process in `htop` and send `SIGKILL` to it manually.

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Comment: @l0b0 Did you wait until `doing task 5  ...` appeared and then hit `Ctrl+C`? Here is a screencast: https://i.imgur.com/l3zY372.mp4
(note that after `ctrl+c`, 4 bash processes remain and one of them is consuming almost all of CPU cycles)